# Vb.net code not performing as Javascript code

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I translated a script from javascript that is correctly computing the APRs on mortgage loans into visual basic code which I'm trying to use on another site. I have posted a link below where you can see the javascript live. Here below is the code and console messages that I'm generating. The button click event starts at the computeForm at the bottom of the code.

```
function CalcLoanPayment(Loan_Amount, Interest_Rate, Term_Years) {
            var A = Loan_Amount;
            var i = Interest_Rate;
            var n = Term_Years;
            var amt = A / CalcPv(i / 12, n * 12);
            console.log("Amount: " + amt);
            return A / CalcPv(i / 12, n * 12);
        }

        function CalcPv(i, n) {
            var num = (1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n)) / i;
            console.log("CalcPv: " + num);
            return (1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n)) / i;
        }

        function CalcAPR(form, Interest_Rate, Term_Years, Points, Fees, Loan_Amount) {
            var i = parseFloat(Interest_Rate);
            var n = parseInt(Term_Years);
            var p = parseFloat(Points);
            var fe = parseFloat(Fees);
            var A = parseFloat(Loan_Amount);
            var f = 0;
            var f1 = 0;
            var iflag = 0;
            //var lp = (CalcLoanPayment(A, i, n) * 12);
            //console.log(lp);

            p = (A * (p * .01));
            f1 = (A - (p + fe)) / (CalcLoanPayment(A, i, n) * 12);
            console.log("A: " + A, "Fees: " + fe, "f1: "  + f1);
            f = 999;
            i = 0;
            while (f > f1) {
                i = i + .01; f = CalcPv(i / 12, n * 12) / 12;
                console.log("i +.01" + i + "f: " + f);
            }
            while (f < f1) {
                i = i - .001; f = CalcPv(i / 12, n * 12) / 12;
                console.log("i -.001" + i + "f: " + f);
            }
            while (f > f1) {
                i = i + .0001; f = CalcPv(i / 12, n * 12) / 12;
                console.log("i + .0001" + i + "f: " + f);
            }
            while (f < f1) {
                i = i - .00001; f = CalcPv(i / 12, n * 12) / 12;
                console.log("i - .00001" + i + "f: " + f);
            }
            while (f > f1) {
                i = i + .000001; f = CalcPv(i / 12, n * 12) / 12;
                console.log("i + .00001" + i + "f: " + f);
            }
            console.log("I: " + i);
            return (i);
        }

        function computeForm(form) {
            if ((form.term.value == null || form.term.value.length == 0) ||
                (form.interest.value == null || form.interest.value.length == 0) ||
                (form.points.value == null || form.points.value.length == 0)) {
                return;
            }

            var i = form.interest.value * .01;
            var j = form.interest.value * .01;
            var n = form.term.value;
            var p = form.points.value;
            var fee = form.fees.value;
            var A = form.amnt.value;
            i = CalcAPR(form, i, n, p, fee, A);
           
            form.AprResult.value = (i * 100);
            form.PmntResult.value = CalcLoanPayment(A, j, n).toFixed(2);
            return;
        }


alcPv: 248.97265725134278
Amount: 1270.189680631263 
CalcPv: 248.97265725134278 
A: 316242.5 Fees: 11787 f1: 19.974411738298457 
CalcPv: 310.9070672073437 
i +.010.01f: 25.90892226727864 
CalcPv: 270.54851648520196 
i +.010.02f: 22.545709707100162 
CalcPv: 237.18938150428227 
i +.010.03f: 19.76578179202352 
CalcPv: 240.25179533325704 
i -.0010.028999999999999998f: 20.020982944438085 
CalcPv: 239.9429959226171 
i + .00010.029099999999999997f: 19.99524966021809 
CalcPv: 239.63476823493866 
i + .00010.029199999999999997f: 19.969564019578222 
CalcPv: 239.66556531131928 
i - .000010.029189999999999997f: 19.97213044260994 
CalcPv: 239.69636809382035 
i - .000010.029179999999999998f: 19.974697341151696 
CalcPv: 239.69328755875875 
i + .000010.029181f: 19.974440629896563 
CalcPv: 239.69020708076602 
i + .000010.029182f: 19.974183923397167 
I: 0.029182 
CalcPv: 248.97265725134278 
Amount: 1270.189680631263 
CalcPv: 248.97265725134278
```

The I at .029182 or 2.9182 % is the correct APR. You can do this live on my website and hit your F12 key to see the same messages. It's at https://pacificwestcapital.net/California_mortgage_rates.aspx
Just scroll down the page. The entries are $316,242.50 for loan amount, 2.625% rate, 30 years, no points and fees are $11787.

In my VB.net code, the APR is different. I calculated 2.727%. I believe that I have translated the code correctly from javascript into vb.net.  The very first number is suspect from the messages. THe 248.9726 is not what I see when I place a breakpoint in the vb.net code. The number I read is 4.57142...nothing close to 248.9726. The 1270.1896 rounded to 1270.19 is the correct monthly payment which is fully amortized over 30 years. The same number and the same breakpoint in the vb.net code is $69,178.04. I assume that Math.pow works exactly the same in vb.net or javascript.  I'm a little lost on how these numbers are so different.  Here is my vb.net code:

```
     Protected Function CalcLoanPayment(ByVal Loan_Amount As Decimal, ByVal Interest_Rate As Decimal, ByVal Term_Years As Int16) As Double
    Dim amt As Double = Loan_Amount / CalcPV(Interest_Rate / 12, Term_Years * 12)
    Return Loan_Amount / CalcPV(Interest_Rate / 12, Term_Years * 12)
End Function

Protected Function CalcPV(ByVal i As Decimal, ByVal n As Int16) As Double
    Dim a As Double = (1 - Math.Pow(1 + i, -n)) / i
    Return (1 - Math.Pow(1 + i, -n)) / i
End Function
Function CalcAPR(ByVal Interest_Rate As Decimal, ByVal Term_Years As Decimal, ByVal Fees As Decimal, ByVal Loan_Amount As Decimal) As Double
    Dim i As Decimal = Interest_Rate
    Dim n As Decimal = Term_Years
    Dim A As Decimal = Loan_Amount
    Dim f As Double = 0
    Dim f1 As Double = 0
    f1 = (A - Fees) / (CalcLoanPayment(A, i, n) * 12)

    f = 999
    i = 0
    While f > f1
        i = i + 0.01
        f = CalcPV(i / 12, n * 12) / 12
    End While
    While f < f1
        i = i - 0.001
        f = CalcPV(i / 12, n * 12) / 12
    End While
    While f > f1
        i = i + 0.0001
        f = CalcPV(i / 12, n * 12) / 12
    End While
    While f < f1
        i = i - 0.00001
        f = CalcPV(i / 12, n * 12) / 12
    End While
    While f > f1
        i = i + 0.000001
        f = CalcPV(i / 12, n * 12) / 12
    End While

    Return (i)
End Function
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code line by line to see exactly where things go awry? That should have been the first thing you did. I'm guessing that the issue will be that divisions are returning different values somewhere because you're dividing by an integer, but that's just a guess.

Comment: To John's comment, in VB, division using a forward slash operator `/` will always return a `Double`.  If you want integer division, you need to use the backward slash operator \.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have am trying to compare numbers. Does a forward slash in javascript result in a double? I guess I need to see everything one calc at a time. I will try to see if I can get every calculation. It is confusing. When I put my breakpoint at the same place as I do a console.log, I should see the same number as in the messages in the log.